# Eignvectors of the Weingarten map/ Shape operator

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f:U \subset R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ be a parameterization of some manifold $\mathcal{M}$. Let $(u,v)$ be the set of coordinates in $U$ then the set $\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\}$ spans the tangent space at a point on $\mathcal{M}$ where the partial derivatives are computed. It can also be interpreted as the set of basis vectors that spans the manifold.

If for some $p\in\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{L}_p : T_p\mathcal{M} \rightarrow T_p\mathcal{M}$
is the shape operator of $\mathcal{M}$ at the point $p$, various sources state for granted that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathcal{L}_p$ and the corresponding eigenvalues are the principle curvatures.

My attempt to prove this was to evaluate, $$\mathcal{L}_p\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\right) = -\nabla_{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}}\nu_p$$ which is the covariant derivative of the gauss map $\nu$ at $p$ along the direction $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$. By doing this I hope to go through a series of simplification such that the right hand side of the equation boils down to some constant times $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$. But I can't seem to find those simplifications and seek for hints or a solution.

Comment: No, this is false. A parametrization $(u,v) \mapsto f(u,v)$ for a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ has both partial derivatives $f_u$ and $f_v$ be the eigenvectors of the shape operator if and only if $\langle f_u,f_v\rangle = \langle f_{uv},\nu\rangle = 0$. This is somewhat a standard result, but the only exact reference I know quickly and off the top of my head is Proposition 3.5.6 (p. 210) in my own book *Introduction to Lorentz Geometry: Curves and Surfaces* (link in my profile, sorry for self-advertising). I know for a fact that this is somewhere in do Carmo's book too, I just don't recall where...

Comment: @IvoTerek what if we were to choose a parameterization such that the partial derivatives were orthonormal, so we can go ahead with the problem, or is it not the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: This is also no good: such a parametrization exists if and only if the surface is flat (i.e., zero Gaussian curvature).

Comment: @IvoTerek So basically, its not always possible to find a parameterization the partial derivatives of which point in the principle directions?

Comment: Yes, that was the very first thing I said...